# Does flutter_local_notifications library works in background of app?

Tags: flutter

Does flutter_local_notifications library works in background of app? I want to ask if the Flutter local notifications library works even if leave my app?

Answer (score 0):

it does works if you added the notification for the background activity and have registered it.